# How do you change an existing table's owner and tablespace in Enterprise Architect 14?

Tags: enterprise-architect

In version 14, changes to an existing table's owner and tablespace aren't saving when I press `Apply` or `OK`.

[image]

I do not receive any errors, but if I close and then re-open the dialog window for the table, the old data is still present.

Other changes to the table, such as new fields are saved correctly.

Are there additional configuration changes at 14 that need to occur for owner and namespace edits to be successful?

Version: 14.0.1423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have found a bug in EA. Please [report](https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html) it to Sparx so it can get fixed.

As a workaround you can edit the corresponding tagged values in the **Tags** tab of the same dialog.